# Computing the likelihood of data for Binomial Distribution

Tags: julia

I am following the book (Statistical Rethinking) which has code in R and want to reproduce the same in code in Julia. In the book, they compute the likelihood of six successes out of 9 trials where a success, has a probability of 0.5. They achieve this using the following R code.

```
 #R Code
 dbinom(6, size = 9, prob=0.5)
 #Out > 0.1640625
```

I am wondering how to do the same in Julia,

```
 #Julia
 using Distributions
 
 b = Binomial(9,0.5)
 # Its possible to look at random value,
 rand(b)
 #Out > 5
```

But how do I look at a specific value such as six successes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you know this but just to be sure the r `dbinom` function is the  probability density (mass) function for the Binomial distribution.

Julia's `Distributions` package makes use of multiple dispatch to just have one generic `pdf` function that can be called with any type of `Distribution` as the first argument, rather than defining a bunch of methods like `dbinom`, `dnorm` (for the Normal distribution). So you can do:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> b = Binomial(9, 0.5)
Binomial{Float64}(n=9, p=0.5)

julia> pdf(b, 6)
0.1640625000000001
```

There is also `cdf` which works in the same way to calculate (maybe unsurprisingly) for the cumulative density function.